# Shortcode to show the code

Tags: php, shortcode

how can I create a shortcode (or something similar) to show the footer in somewhere on a page?

I tried with this but no results...

```
function show_footer() {
    return get_footer();
}
add_shortcode( 'show_f', 'show_footer' );
```

or this...

```
function show_footer() {
    get_footer();
}
add_shortcode( 'show_f', 'show_footer' );
```

any idea?

many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_footer()` echos the contents of the footer.php file. `add_shortcode()` requires that the callback return the contents of the shortcode and not echo it. I suppose you could do something like this if you really want.

```
function show_footer() {
  ob_start();
  get_footer();
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'show_f', 'show_footer' );
```